# Class constructor that takes a reference to a different object and I would like to not copy the object

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a student learning c++.
I have two objects ("City" and "Parser") and I'd like one object("Parser") to modify to other one("City").
The only "problem" is that I have to send the object("City") in the other one's constructor (The code is showing what I mean).

```
    class City {
    public:
        City()
            : peopleCount { 0 }
        {};

        int peopleCount;
    };

    class Parser {
    public:
        Parser(const char *filename, City &c)
            : _filename { filename },
              _c { c }
        {};

        void fillCity() { _c.peopleCount = 3; };

        const char *_filename;
        City _c;
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        City c;
        Parser p(argv[1], c);

        p.fillCity();
        std::cout << c.peopleCount << std::endl; // I would like my output to be "3"
        return 0;
    }
```

I could do that in C by sending a raw pointer in the constructor.
But since I discover this langage, everyone is saying that raw pointer must be avoided.
I checked smart pointers but they would "delete" my variable (my variable is from the Stack, for that reason I don't want to delete it).
I do not want to copy the "City" in the "Parser" (because copying objects can be avoided ?).

I am aware that I could send a reference of a City object to the member function "fillCity" but I would like to know if the one object can hold another object without copying it.

Is there another way to do that without using raw pointer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Never use elements of `argv` without checking `argc` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Parser` constructor, you pass the `City` argument by reference. But then you *copy* the object to store it in `_c`.

You should make `_c` a reference as well.

Comment: That works ! Thanks.  I did not know that we could declare references.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share objects while having the life time of these objects under control, you can use `shared_ptr`. Thereby, the shared object will be destructed once all references to it have been released (i.e. the last `shared_ptr`-wrapper got destructed):

```
class City {
public:
    City()
    : peopleCount(0)
    {};

    int peopleCount;
};

class Parser {
public:
    Parser(const char *filename, std::shared_ptr<City> c)
    : _filename (filename),
    _c (c) {};

    void fillCity() { _c->peopleCount = 3; };

    const char *_filename;
    std::shared_ptr<City> _c;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<City> c = std::make_shared<City>();
    Parser p("somefilename", c);

    p.fillCity();
    std::cout << c->peopleCount << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (after Some Programmer Dude's correct answer) is to pass c in as a reference to some of P's member functions, e.g.:

```
class Parser {
public:
    Parser(const char *filename)
        : _filename { filename }
    {};
    void fillCity(City &c) { c.peopleCount = 3; };
    const char *_filename;
};
```

Used like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    City c;
    Parser p(argv[1]);

    p.fillCity(c);
    std::cout << c.peopleCount << std::endl; // I would like my output to be "3"
    return 0;
}
```

This may or may not be how you want it - but if you just have one or a small number of functions this is quite convinient.

On another point - I would not say passing-by-pointer is so bad, for example you can at least default construct with a pointer (default value being nullptr) and then later pass in the `C` object. The only "issue" is that you need to be careful that `C` exists for the lifetime of `P` or that you tell `P` if/when `C` dissapears... not really rocket sceince :) and it can be quite convinient.